# Change order of integral

Tags: integration, partial-derivative

I've got the following integral:
$\int_0^T{\int_{\Omega}{\partial_t u(x,t)dxdt}}$

I would like to change the order of the integral, so that I become
$\int_{\Omega}{\int_0^T{\partial_t u(x,t)dtdx}}
= \int_{\Omega}{(u(T,x)-u(0,x))dx} $

But I'm doubting what's the correct reason for doing this. I think that you can change the order here because $x$ and $t$ are independent. Is that correct?

Comment: To the degree that $\Omega$ does not depend on $t$, yes, under some regularity conditions (see Fubini as the answer suggested) you can interchange the order of integration in the straightforward way you write in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For changing the order of integration check [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem).